# char_length and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to return the char_length of a specific field in the database. I can run the query in the PHPmyADMIN SQL code entry form and it works fine, but when I try to retrieve it using the same query and mysql_fetch_assoc(), it returns the word array. Can someone give me the correct code to retrieve this value?

Comment: Can you provide the query you are using.

Comment: "SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(title) FROM table1 WHERE id= '7'"

Answer (score 1):

That's because `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an array, even if it is only returning one value. Without knowing the column name you're looking for I can't tell you more, but try var_dump on the output of `mysql_fetch_assoc`. You should see something like:

```
array(1) {
  ["my_column_names_char_length"]=>
  int(255)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do is:

```
 $query = "SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(title) FROM table1 WHERE id= '7'";
 $charLength = array_shift(mysql_fetch_row($query));
```

$charLength will either be NULL if the query returned no results or the value you were getting before.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php and 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php